# ngx-translate in terinory condtion in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

here  the issue is ngx translate in  ternary condtion  .

```
{{ (videoConfig === true) ? 'Disable Video' : 'Enable Video' }}
```

i want to  translate the word disable video and enable video  in that condtion .how it is possible please help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
{{ ((videoConfig == true) ? 'Disable Video' : 'Enable Video') | translate }}
```

or even

```
{{ (videoConfig  ? 'Disable Video' : 'Enable Video') | translate }}
```

should work also

Comment: im using  json like 
 "echotest": {
    "Audioinputsource": "Audio input source",
    "Audiooutputdestination": "Audio output destination",
    "Videosource": "Video source",
    "Disableaudio": "Disable Audio",
    " Disablevideo": "Disable Video",
    "Enableaudio":" Enable Audio",
    "Enablevideo":"Enable video"
  },
how to   use this

Comment: i think it should be like ```{{ ((videoConfig == true) ? 'echotest.Disablevideo' : 'echotest.Enablevideo') | translate }}```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the ternary operator into () and it should be good.

```
{{ ((videoConfig === true) ? 'Disable Video' : 'Enable Video') | translate }}
```