# how to use ngx-translate for Conditional (ternary) operator?

Tags: ngx-translate

How can i use ngx translate for a Conditional (ternary) operator?

For example:

```
<ion-badge [tooltip]="editMode ? 'Status' : 'Change'>{{ status }}</ion-badge>
```

I like to use nxg-translate for  'Status' and for 'Change'.

```
''Status' | translate' dooes not work. Also
```

'"Status" | translate' not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ngx-translate in terinory condtion in angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874618/ngx-translate-in-terinory-condtion-in-angular-8)